# LINQtoXSD - Using typed code and getting blank xmlns (xmlns = "")

Tags: xml, linq, xsd, xml-namespaces

All solutions I've found so far use the XmlDocument. I am currently using typed XML without using XElement.

Is there a clean/proper way to get rid of it?

Here is the code I'm running:

```
 aseXML ase = new aseXML();
 ase.Header = new Header();
 ase.Save("test.xml");
```

The contents of test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<aseXML xmlns="urn:aseXML:r26">
  <Header xmlns="" />
</aseXML>
```

However the content I want is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<aseXML xmlns="urn:aseXML:r26">
  <Header/>
</aseXML>
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of `aseXML` and `Header`?

Comment: They are classes generated from [link](http://www.aemo.com.au/asexml/schemas.html#r26)
The declaration in the generated code look like this:

    `public partial class aseXML : XTypedElement, IXMetaData`

and `public Header()`